# Database Junction Tables - Default Flag Column

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-performance

I have a many-to-many relationship between two models: customers and addresses. A customer has many addresses, but one of them would be a default address. I figured creating the junction table with a `customer_id`, `address_id`, and `default` columns would be the way to go. The `default` column would be a boolean. But is that right? There would be mostly 0 values, with the occasional 1.

Another person told me to just keep the junction table without the `default` column, and instead save the default address in the `customers` table as `address_id`. The argument was for storage space since the extra column in the junction table is not needed, and that we don't need an extra join to get the default address ID.

However, from a data structure standpoint, I think having the default flag in the junction table makes more sense. Also, storage is not going to be an issue.

I'd love to hear some other input on this and any best practices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the association is many to many this means that the same address could be associated to multiple customers, right? And different customers can have the same address as default as well?

Comment: That's correct. Imagine customers within the same household. They would share the same address, and the address would be related to many orders. And each of the customers would select a default or primary address.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a many:many relationship ("junction table") "customer CUSTOMER has address ADDRESS" and a 0-or-1-to-0-or-1 "customer CUSTOMER's default address is ADDRESS". There's a foreign key on (CUSTOMER, ADDRESS) from the latter to the former. If a default address is optional and you want to have it as a property of a customer then you could make it NULLable. (But this introduces a circularity involving foreign keys which most DBMSs needlessly choke on.)

There is no point in trying to "optimize" without many more specifics in place, plus a smell, plus patterns of use, plus present cost-benefit of options, plus (if done) verification. You seem still far from the experience necessary to persue that process. Just make the most straightforward design.